# How go back from Fragment A to Fragment B?

Tags: android, back, onbackpressed

I need to go from FragmentA to FragmentB (i'm using navigationdrawer)

I create this method in FragmentB:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

but they don't work, how can i implement this method?

Comment: **replace** fragment B with Fragment A

Comment: How can i do? can you show me an exemple?

Comment: Please refer to the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Comment: @Rotwang i need to do with "back" button, in the bottom of the phone Left

Comment: And what does prevent you from doing that in the `onBackPressed()` event of your Activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add your fragment, you also have to add it to your fragment's backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                  ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment, backStateName);
                  ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
                  ft.commit();
```

(here R.id.content is your fragment container in your activity)

Then you have to override onBackPressed method in your activity that contains your fragments.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  }
}
```

if you want to customize your onBackPressed then you can check for your currently visible fragment in your activity and create a callback for performing action for that particular fragment.
example -

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
              Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
              if (fragment instanceof FragmentB) {
                            ((FragmentB) fragment).onBackPressed();
//                     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
      }
    }
```

now you can add getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); in your Fragment's onBackPressed() method.

Comment: you can take your class name as String backStateName = FragmentB.class.getName();

Answer (score 0):

This code should be inside `Activity` holding both fragments.

Be sure, that you add (not replace) the fragment to back stack, by calling:

```
android.app.FragmentTransaction#add(int, android.app.Fragment, java.lang.String)
android.app.FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack
android.app.FragmentTransaction#commit
```

or their equivalent from support library

Comment: Oh tnks now i put my `onBackPressed()` method in my activity but now when i click "back button" he don't do nothing..

Comment: Are you surem that Backstack is not empty? If it is empty, you shoud call `super.onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score 0):

For going to the one fragment to another I am calling the Activity's method from Fragment so that the Activity's method has access to that view which is holding fragment and it can switch easily.

like this in my Fragment

> ((MainActivity) getActivity()).TransitionFromItemToCategory();

And in the fragment Like this

```
public void TransitionFromItemToCategory(){
    FoodCategoryFragment FCM = new FoodCategoryFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, FCM);
    ft.commit();
}
```